# The conundrum about .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Folder structure:

```
web
- bar
  - index.php // echo 'you are inside bar'
  - .htaccess
- foo
  - index.php // echo 'you are inside foo'
  - .htaccess
```

What I must write in .htaccess in bar that at request bar/page launched  index.php from foo folder?

Comment: Does it need to be in the subdirectory htaccess or can it be in root htaccess

Comment: @ChrisMaggiulli apache look at `web/bar`

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  I'm asking if you can use the root .htaccess or if your requirement is specifically asking for this to work in the bar .htacess file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in `bar/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^page(/.*)?$ /foo/index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, but it's a little not what I need. It forwards all requests. It is only necessary from the `bar/page` subdirectory. For example:
`bar/on -> bar`, `bar/two -> bar`, `bar/page -> foo`

Comment: Thank you. You are the best!